# java nio create directory cyrillic name

Tags: java, java-8, nio

I want create directory with cyrillic name. But when I did it, I get normal folder and folder with not correct name.
How I can fix it? I need only 1 folder with correct name.

```
 public void addEntry(String name, InputStream inputStream)
    throws IOException {

    if (inputStream == null) {
      return;
    }

    try (FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(
        _uri, Collections.emptyMap())) {

      Path path = fileSystem.getPath(name);

      Path parentPath = path.getParent();

      if (parentPath != null) {
        Files.createDirectories(parentPath); //here is creating 
      }

      Files.copy(inputStream, path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
  }
```

[image: 2 folders]

Comment: Please post, *as text* the name you want, and tell us what OS you're using, and the output of `System.out.println(java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset());`

Comment: I suggest that you post a [mcve]. Post code that calls method `addEntry`. Then post the result that you want to get after running method `addEntry` and also post the result that you are getting now.

Comment: @Abra sorry, but I can't write code that run method `addEntry` here.

Comment: @g00se I use windows. The output of `System.out.println(java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset());` is `UTF-8`

Comment: And the name as text is..?

Comment: @g00se _/test_тестовая_папка/test1.jpg_

Comment: OK. Why in fact are you using `FileSystems.newFileSystem`? Is it not your regular file system you want to use?

Comment: @g00se I use it because i download file. And when download this code create folder and parent folders for the file that i download. For example, in my UI i have folder _test_тестовая_папка_ and file in it _test1.jpg_. I click download on folder and then this code is executed. And folders was created on my computer as in the screen.

Comment: Apologies for no formatting in comments, but why not just: `public static void saveInputStreamAsFile(Path targetDir, InputStream in, String fileName) throws IOException {Path target = Path.of(targetDir.toString(), fileName);Files.copy(in, target);}` ?

Comment: @g00se actually, I download a folder with files. So, if I have _/test_dir/test1.img_,  _/test_dir/test2.img_, I click download on _test_dir_, I should get on my computer dir with name  _test_dir_ and 2 files in it.

Comment: Well it's pretty easy to fix up what I gave you to cope with that

Comment: @g00se is copy create folder too? I mean if I have _/test_1/test_2/test_3/test.png_ and on my computer I don't have any of this folder, will I have them all after use method `copy`?

Comment: It’s impossible to match your code with the task you’re describing in the comments. This code doesn’t “download a folder with files”. It receives *a single `InputStream`* as input. Then, it creates a new filesystem at `_uri`. It’s still not clear why or what `_uri` is pointing to.

Comment: You can make this the first line of the code I gave you: `if (!Files.exists(targetDir)) { Files.createDirectories(targetDir); }`

Comment: @g00se I have this in my code. It works fine for English letters, but not correctly for Cyrillic letters.

Comment: @Holger uri - it is where my jar file is exist on server. So I get folder with file from server to my computer.

Comment: So, this code is *running on the server* and *copying a file into a jar file*? And all the stuff about “download a folder with files” you’re talking about, is entirely irrelevant to this code? And we had to ask for five days, to eventually get the actual purpose of the code you have problems with?

Comment: If the main problem is that you are having difficulty creating a file/folder with Cyrillic letters, then you should be testing using code that's even simpler. Probably just the single line `Files.createDirectories(pathWithCyrillicName);`

Comment: @g00se yes, if I did this code I get 1 directory with wrong name.

Comment: @g00se I use `zipfilesystem` proveder for create this directory.

Comment: Out of interest, what is the value of system property `sun.jnu.encoding`? Obviously, a significant matter in your screenshot is that evidently paths with Cyrillic letters are fine as far as your OS is concerned, but one of them is looking very wrong. You should probably post *in your question* the one-liner we just discussed showing the problem of creating such a path. And possibly the result in the file manager as screenshot

Comment: You create a zip/jar file, add entries to it, transfer it to another computer, extract it there, to find that the *end result* is wrong and do *not* actually know which step in this chain causes the error. In fact, the lack of a binding standard regarding file name encoding in zip files implies that a disagreement between creator and extractor does not indicate an error on either side. The zip fs provider [supports specifying a name encoding](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/jdk.zipfs/module-summary.html#zip-file-system-properties-heading) but you need to know which you need.

Comment: That's all good @Holger, but seemingly we are being told that the simple `Files.createDirectories` is failing irrespective of zip files

Comment: @g00se Are you sure that the OP tested whether `Files.createDirectories(…)` is “failing irrespective of zip files”? You seem to assume that when you say “simple”, the OP understands that you mean “with a `Path` belonging to the local filesystem rather than zip filesystem”.

Comment: Yes, we'd better check that. Please comment @AnnKont